# finding canonical form of a word (related to mergeSort, java)

Tags: java, mergesort, canonical-form

I am stuck at making the canonical form of a word(canonical form of a word contains the same letters as the original word, yet in sorted order. eg. canonical form of "computer" is "cemoprtu" (consider their alphabetical order), that of "program" is "agmoprr". )

I use mergeSort to sort the letters of a word, using the following code. Yet it just give me the original word instead of the canonical form. can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
public static String canonicalForm(String word) {
    char[] string = new char[word.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i ++) {
        string[i] = word.charAt(i);
    }
    mergeSort(string);
    String result = "";
    for (char ch: string) {
        result += ch;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static void mergeSort(char[] string) {
    if (string.length > 1) {
        char[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(string, 0, string.length/2);
        char[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(string, string.length/2, string.length);
        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);
        merge(string, left, right);
    }
}

public static void merge(char[] string, char[] left, char[] right) {
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i ++) {
        if (i1 < left.length) {
            if (left[i1] - right[i2] <= 0) {
                string[i] = left[i1];
                i1 ++;
            }
        } else if (i2 >= right.length) {
            string[i] = left[i1];
            i1 ++;
        } else {
            string[i] = right[i2];
            i2 ++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flaw is that your merge doesn't copy symbols from right part if **left[i1] - right[i2] > 0**.

This works:

```
public static void merge(char[] string, char[] left, char[] right) {
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (i1 < left.length && i2 < right.length) {
            if (left[i1] - right[i2] <= 0) {
                string[i] = left[i1];
                i1++;
            } else {
                string[i] = right[i2];
                i2++;
            }
        } else if (i2 >= right.length) {
            string[i] = left[i1];
            i1++;
        } else {
            string[i] = right[i2];
            i2++;
        }
    }
}
```

You have three cases:

1. There are symbols available **in both parts**. Take one with the least value.
2. There are symbols available **only in the left part**. Copy them.
3. There are symbols available **only in the right part**. Copy them.

Comment: i see, i do the conditional parts wrongly. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why You are reinventing the wheel, but this can be written without custom implementation of sorting, String concatenating etc.

```
public static String canonicalForm(final String word) {
    final char[] string = word.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(string);
    final String result = new String(string);
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It's always good to know how things could be done in a simpler way. But knowing basics, and merge sort is definitely one of the most important algorithms, is a MUST. So I would definetelly vote for inventing a wheel here.

Comment: oh, in fact as a beginner, i am learning mergeSort, so the task requires me to do it this way. yet your answer is useful, thx for the help.

Comment: @user3462533 You could try to optimize Your code to avoid unnecessary copying of array parts (get rid of `Arrays.copyOfRange`) in favor of specifying additional parameters in methods that hold low /mid/ high indexes.

Comment: Then you are better do that way: 1) Write the simplest code possible. 2) Write some unit-tests to prove it works. 3) Refactor with you hands untied.

Comment: sorry, but i dont quite get the meaning of "avoid unnecessary copying of array parts", i dont know if there is any method instead of using Arrays.copyOfRange(). is there any?

Comment: No, there isn't, that's why I commented about additional parameters in methods to pass positions in sorted array. So instead of `mergeSort(char[] string)` it would be `mergeSort(char[] string, int low, int high) ` and `public static void merge(char[] string, char[] left, char[] right)` would be `public static void merge(char[] string, int leftPos, int midPos, int rightPos)`